# How do I convert a char string to an integer in Java?

Tags: java, string, bluej

For example:
I have a string that says "Yams". 
I want to turn it into a single integer "8997109115".
How do I do that?

Comment: Turning "Yams" into "8997109115"? What's the connection between the two strings? And why should this input give exactly that output?

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl He wants to take the char value and not add them but combine them into a string then convert it to a number.

Answer (score 2):

You will not want to use an integer since this will get very large very fast and a long will not even hold some strings.

Use this:

```
String yams = "Yams";
String con = "";
for(int i = 0; i < yams.length(); i++){
    con += (int) yams.charAt(i);
}
long singleLong = Long.parseLong(con);
```

This will first convert the string to a string with the values of the chars with the for loop.  Since it is all numbers you can then use Long.parseLong(string) to convert it to a long.  Be careful because if you make the string too long it will give you a number format exception because the number is too large.

Comment: Thanks.  I should've added that "8997109115" is all of the ascii codes glommed together.  I guess you figured that out anyway.  Out of curiosity, about how long do you think that integer could get before it gives an error?

Comment: A integer can only have a max size of 2,147,483,647 and a min size of -2,147,483,647.  If anything you may be better off leaving it as a string (depending on what you need it for).

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to convert a String varible into an Integer. You can "extract" an integer from a string :

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");
```

But in your example it cannot be preformed.

Comment: Yes it can.  The code I posted does exactly what he has asked.  You can convert it to an integer because each char can be casted to an integer.  You can then combine the integers and make it a string of numbers which can be parsed. (As long as it is not too big of a number.  Try running the code I posted.  It outputs what he wants it to output.

Comment: Thank you. But I think he should have at least gave precisions that the binary code of "Yams" is "8997109115" in base 10.